How to mock dll function using Gmock?
I have searched on this and did not find much information.
I have a below pattern of code where I have 1 class dedicated to load and unload dll in constructor and destructor respectively. Also the class has member variables which will hold the address to the functions to the dll.
Now this DllLoader is used by some other class. I want to mock the DllLoader so that the test I write for other class is specific to that function.
Example:
typedef int(*fun_ptr)(int);

class DllLoader {
public:
DllLoader(const std::string& dll_name) : handle(nullptr), fun1(nullptr) {

handle = ::LoadLibrary(dll_name);
fun1 = (fun_ptr1)GetProcAddress(handle, "DLLFunction1");
}

fun_ptr1 fun1;
HANDLE handle;
};

class SomeClass {
public:
SomeClass(DllLoader* dll_loader) : dll(dll_loader) {}

void init() {

int res = dll->fun1(100); // I want to use mock for fun1() call. Exception!!!
if(res < 50) {
//
}
else {
//
}
}

DllLoader* dll;
};

I have tried the below, but I get exception while calling the fun1() inside init(). What am I doing wrong here?
I have not tested the code given as example here. But the flow is same.
//created a mock class for DllLoader
class MockDllLoader : public DllLoader {
public:
MockDllLoader() : DllLoader("");
MOCK_METHOD(int, fun1, (int));
}; 


TEST(SomeClassTest, TestInit) {
MockDllLoader *mock_dll_loader = new MocDllLoader();
SomeClass * some_class = new SomeClass(mock_dll_loader);
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_dll_loader, fun1(::testing::_)).WillOnce(Return(1000));

EXPECT_NO_THROW({
some_class->init(); //expecting init to use the mocked function
});
}


The problem is, that you cannot use MOCK_METHOD for fun1, because it is not a virtual method, just a plain data member.

As I see from the example code, fun1 is actually public, so the easiest way would be to set the value to a real (but dummy) function. But I guess in real life it is private..

This question is similar to: Mocking free function. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@3CxEZiVlQ, may I know how is this related to Mocking free function?


Define some interface:

class SomeFunctionality
{
public:
    virtual ~SomeFunctionality();
    virtual int function1(int) = 0;
};

//cpp
SomeFunctionality::~SomeFunctionality() = default;


Provide implementation of this interface for production case, when dll is used:

class SomeFunctionalityFromDll : public SomeFunctionality
{
public:
    explicit SomeFunctionalityFromDll(const std::string& dll_name)
    {
        handle = ::LoadLibrary(dll_name);
        fun1 = (fun_ptr1)GetProcAddress(handle, "DLLFunction1");
    }

    ~SomeFunctionalityFromDll()
    {
        FreeLibrary(handle);
    }

    SomeFunctionalityFromDll(const SomeFunctionalityFromDll&) = delete;
    SomeFunctionalityFromDll& operator=(const SomeFunctionalityFromDll&) = delete;

    int function1(int x) override
    {
        return fun1(x);
    }

private:
    fun_ptr1 fun1;
    HANDLE handle;
};


Use interface in production code:

class SomeClass {
public:
    explicit SomeClass(SomeFunctionality* dependency) : dependency(dependency) 
    {}

    void init() {
        int res = dependency->function1(100);
        if(res < 50) {
            //
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
    SomeFunctionality* dependency;
};


Then providing a mock is trivial:

class MockSomeFunctionality : public SomeFunctionality
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, function1, (int), (override));
};


And writing test code is simple too:

TEST(SomeClassTest, initWillInvokeFunction1)
{
    MockSomeFunctionality mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, function1(100)).WillOnce(::testing::Return(12));
    SomeClass prodClass{&mock};
    prodClass.init();
}

https://godbolt.org/z/KbevWWcnn
The disadvantage is that you have extra indirection to call "DLLFunction1". If this is a problem it can be removed by static polymorphism (using templates).

yes, this is one of the ways to do it. I was searching for something which can follow some other approach than this, as this would involve making the changes in the original code. However, seems like this is the only way and it worked for me. Thank you.

Making a code easily testable is hard.
However, in your example code (if fun1 is public) it can be as simple, as setting a member variable.
Here is a low cost solution, by setting the value to a dummy function. Of course, if you need the mocking ability, you can make the return_self function to create a mock object and set some expectations.
typedef int(*fun_ptr)(int);

class DllLoader {
public:
    DllLoader() {
        handle = ::LoadLibrary(dll_name);
        fun1 = (fun_ptr1)GetProcAddress(handle, "DLLFunction1");
    }

    fun_ptr fun1;
    HANDLE handle;
};

int return_self(int i) {
    return i;
};

int main(void)
{
    DllLoader d;
    d.fun1 = &return_self;
    
    std::cout << d.fun1(10);
    return 0;
}

In case it is not public (but you can change the DllLoader class), I would go with creating an interface above the DllLoader, and using a mocked interface in the unit test, and the real DllLoader in the real application.
Something like this:
class IDllLoader {
public:
    void callFunction() = 0;
};

class DllLoader : public IDllLoader {
...
};

Then it would be just as easy as passing a mocked IDllLoader to your SomeClass and then you can set up your tests.
By using the interface, you could also avoid calling the constructor of a real DllLoader, therefore skipping the ::LoadLibrary and getProcAddress calls (what I think would be nice during unit testing).

The simple way to add return_self is good and is working, I am not facing the exception anymore. So basically, since fun1 was a nullptr I was facing the exception. But I cannot proceed with this method, as I have given just an example, the parameters are more complex in real case and I have many functions, not just 1. So cannot write dummy functions for all the actual functions. However, thank you for the reply.
